# Use e-mail address from Git commit to send Jenkins notifications

Tags: git, email, notifications, jenkins

I have set up a Jenkins job with the Git plugin and now want to use the [email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin to send failure notifications to the e-mail address specified in the breaking commit. But then I always get

`"An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored"`

so it seems the e-mail addresses are not extracted. I do not want to create separate user accounts for everyone if possible, and even if I do, how to relate them with Git commits? (the option "Create new accounts base on author/committer's email" would probably scan *all* previous commits which may create wrong users because some people didn't set up the e-mail address correctly – thus I only want it for new commits)

Does anyone have a working setup with either e-mail plugin?

Comment: All the team should add email like `git config --global user.email "me@here.com"`

Comment: I use "E-mail Notification" with default configuration (email suffix is defined to @mycompany.pl) Mail is sent to every who broken the build. Separate mail to each user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GIT Plugin and Email-ext should support it by now. I tried it, and it works. The information comes from this forum:

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jenkins.user/17553

So update your plugins and try again.

Comment: Yes actually I wrote that message, just forgot I had asked in on SO as well ;)

Comment: Hehe. That is really funny.